# BIOS setting: AHCI or RAID (when using SSD + 2x hard drive in RAID-0)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid, ahci

I want to add a new SSD and use it as system drive with Windows 7 x64 installed.
As driver I chose newest Intel Rapid Storage driver (not MSAHCI). I know that I have to use AHCI as BIOS setting for optimal SSD read/write performance. But I'm also using 2 normal hard drives as separate RAID-0

> SSD: Windows 7
>   hard drive: RAID-0
>   hard drive: RAID-0

If I set my BIOS on my Asus P5W DH Deluxe to **AHCI, my RAID-0 cant be recognized**
And If I'm using **RAID** as setting, maybe my **SSD has not its top speed**. But I'm not sure about that.

> In short:
>   AHCI > no RAID-0
>   RAID > no optimal SSD performance (?)

Now my question: Can I use RAID as BIOS setting and be sure, that theres no decrease in SSD performance?

---

*Google finds so many articles with similar topics and my head is just exploding. Two examples:

- set AHCI and after installing OS switch to RAID as BIOS setting... what?

- use a diskette and F6 while installing Windows 7... really? O.o I thought those times are gone*

Comment: Honestly you won't notice the speed difference between AHCI and RAID, even if you only had the SSD in your machine.

Comment: @nixda - Why the unaccept two years after the fact? o.O

Comment: @shinrai I recently expanded my system with additional drives and recreated the raid. I did some research and found this [link](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-ahci-and-raid/) which states "RAID is more advantageous for people compared to AHCI" and I remembered this question. I think there is a difference between them and I should unaccept it so no one get pointed in the wrong direction. Now I have read my question again and I saw I was just asking about speed, not about differences in general. I will accept it again. Nevermind :)

Comment: It's worth noting as well - that link is really out of date.  AHCI has not been Intel-exclusive for quite some time.  (I would say most of what it says is still relatively true, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAID should support everything AHCI does for an SSD that isn't actually in an array; no reason for concern.

(On a tangential note, I've benchmarked better speeds using the msahci driver than the Intel one even on Intel drives.  If you're that concerned you might check it out.)

Answer (score 2):

There is one **important** thing to be noted here:

As soon as your RAID is built, it is identified by the OS as a single whole and you cannot access its constituents separately. This may be inconvenient. For example, **you won't be able to update the firmware** or view the S.M.A.R.T. information or perform a Secure Erase for the SSDs in your RAID. But the biggest problem is that **the OS won't be able to use the TRIM command** which is supposed to protect SSDs from performance degradation.

***To sum up***, SATA RAID controllers, including those in modern chipsets, do not support the TRIM command. As a result, the array’s writing performance degrades over time whereas single SSDs are less susceptible to this problem.

Comment: Depending on the SSDs, their manufacturer may have software that will let you mess with them individually even through a RAID array (for the purposes of upgrading firmware, etc).  I know Intel supports this to an extent.